# How do i get my colorbox to open onLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, onload

This link works perfect:

```
<a href='#' onclick='window.parent.jQuery.colorbox({href:"test.php"}); return false;'>
    CLICK HERE 
</a>
```

How do i code this so that when someone goes to my page it will automatically open the window with these settings above?

it should open that link onLoad in the parent window

any ideas?

Comment: What have you researched? What have you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/34v22/ is this what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
<body onload='window.parent.jQuery.colorbox({href:"test.php"}); return false;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery already:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // do something. 
});
```

You may want to use  `.load()` instead of `.ready()`, depending on your needs. Basically the difference is `load` waits until all the images on the page have loaded, whereas `ready` doesn't.  [Here are the docs](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).